# problem in understanding a paper about automorphism in p-groups

Tags: finite-groups, p-groups, automorphism-group

I was trying to read "[NON-INNER AUTOMORPHISMS OF ORDER p IN FINITE p-GROUPS OF COCLASS 3](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1604.08034.pdf)" by MARCO RUSCITTI, LEIRE LEGARRETA, AND MANOJ K. YADAV but found few theorem confusing
 in page 5 Definition 3.1 we have
[image]
after few lemmas and remarks
Then in page 8 we have Theorem 4.1
[image]
then Arthur say that Hypothesis B is much stronger than Hypothesis A and every all the results proved in the preceding section under Hypothesis A are also true under Hypothesis B.
confusing part is that in Hypothesis A we have $=$ but in theorem 4.1 part (i) we have $\not =$ so we cant above result
so is there is a typo or i missing some thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"None of these things holding" means the first one (i) doesn't, which means Hyp A holds. Hence Hyp B implies Hyp A, so B is indeed stronger.

Comment: I read it many times but i didnt  know why i never notice word none

Comment: @user148528  it happens to all of us.